# How exactly does the cd ./ command work in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, cd

I'm just curious, when I'm using the `cd` command in bash, commands

```
cd foobar
```

and

```
cd ./foobar
```

work in the same way. I understand, that ./ refers to the current <s>catalogue</s> directory, but why then does "`cd foobar`" work? Is it just default, that when I'm not writing `./` on the beginning, program adds it on its own, or is it more complicated?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is legitimately a question about software development as opposed to user-level semantics. Consider SuperUser or http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of thing in the future.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: [source code for unix environments 'cd' command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881560/source-code-for-unix-environments-cd-command)

Comment: It seems to me to be a perfectly legitimate question for SO.  It should be considered as 'and what would I need to do to implement it' or thereabouts.

Comment: If the real question is what one needs to do to implement their own shell, asking about bash as opposed to about the baseline POSIX specification's requirements is making a great deal of extra work for oneself.

Answer (score 9):

The `cd` command in bash (somewhat indirectly, as described below) invokes the `chdir()` syscall, [behavior of which is specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chdir.html). The `cd` shell comand itself [also has a POSIX specification for its behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cd.html), in perhaps more detail than is appropriate for an accessible/readable definition.

Yes, the default for all operations (not only `chdir()` but also `fopen()` and others) is the current working directory.

This isn't specific to bash, but is operating-system-level behavior: "Current working directory" is part of the metadata about each process tracked by the kernel, and impacts filesystem-level requests made to the kernel: Any program, in any language, can call `chdir("foo")` or `open("foo", O_RDONLY)`, and behavior will be to look for `foo` in the current directory, as inherited from the parent process or modified with prior `chdir()` calls.

---

That said, for the purposes of bash, `cd ./foo` is more specific than merely `cd foo`: The former says that you **explicitly** want the `foo` subdirectory of the current working directory. In bash, if the `CDPATH` shell variable is set, then `cd foo` will look in all directories listed in it, whereas `cd ./foo` explicitly only asks for `foo` under the current working directory.

Try this experiment:

```
# setup
tempdir=$(mkdir -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/cdpath-test.XXXXXX")
mkdir -p "$tmpdir/i-am-a-test-directory"
CDPATH=".:$tempdir"

# this works, because CDPATH is honored
cd /
cd i-am-a-test-directory

# this does not, because you're explicitly asking for a directory that does not exist
cd /
cd ./i-am-a-test-directory

# cleanup
rm -rf "$tempdir"
unset CDPATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the `CDPATH` environment variable for the time being, the name after `cd` is a directory path name.  There are only two sorts of path name in Unix:

- absolute names that begin with a `/`
- relative names which don't start with a `/`

All relative names are treated by the kernel as relative to the current directory — as if the name was prefixed by `./`.

If you have `CDPATH` set, it complicates the search, and it is then conceivable that `cd somewhere` and `cd ./somewhere` land you in different directories.  A directory name with no leading `/` and with no leading `.` or `..` component (where `cd .hidden` doesn't count — the leading component is `.hidden`— but `cd ./visible` or `cd ../visible` do count) is searched for using `CDPATH`.

For example, consider this tree structure (only directories shown):

```
.                - current directory
./somewhere
./src
./src/somewhere
```

Suppose you have `CDPATH=src:`.  Then `cd somewhere` will go to `./src/somewhere` and `cd ./somewhere` will go (unsurprisingly) to `./somewhere`.  If you type a name such as `cd src/somewhere`, the `cd` command will search for a sub-directory `/xyz/pqr/src/somewhere` for each directory `/xyz/pqr` on `CDPATH` in turn.  I perpetually use `CDPATH` (7 directories on my own machines; 14 on my work machines).

- Rule of thumb: use `CDPATH=:…whatever…`

That puts the current directory first on the search path, and is usually the most sane behaviour.

A similar story applies to searching for ordinary external (non-aliased, non-function, non-builtin) commands.  Command names that start with a slash are absolute pathnames; command names containing a slash are relative to the current directory; command names without a slash are searched for on `$PATH`.